# Using Git without Sudo in many accounts

Tags: git, ubuntu, sudo

**How can you use Git without Sudo in multiple accounts in one Ubuntu?**

My Ubuntu has many accounts.
The creation of new accounts has made Git inaccessible by me without sudo.

I changed the owner to be me, masi, and the group to be `admin` where the *masi* belongs to.
I have the following permissions for Git

```
800 -rwxrwxrwx 1 masi admin 813744 2009-02-20 23:01 /usr/bin/git
```

I get the following message in trying to use Git

```
git status
fatal: unable to create '.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

I run `find . -iregex ".*index.l.*` which returns no matches so  there seems to be no index.lock in locking the system. I run the same command also with sudo unsuccessfully.

Comment: "The creation of new accounts has made Git inaccessible by me without sudo." You should take this as a sign that something is wrong with either your account, your system configuration, or your installation. That is extremely abnormal behaviour -- git is a normal userspace application, accessible by all ordinary users in a normal Ubuntu install.

Comment: For reference, the correct permissions/ownership for /usr/bin/git* are 755 / root.root, as indicated in hillu's answer. You may have accidentally set the permissions so that only group members or the owner could execute 'git' (ie. permissions are 744 aka -rwxr--r-- rather than 755). Failing to correct those permissions represents a serious security risk to your system.

Comment: I believe several pages on web suggest to perform config with commands like : sudo git config --global user.name "Your Name" and this generates problems in the .git ownership. In multi-user OS, it is way better to use git config without sudo.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need grant several *nix user accounts write access to the same git repository. Using the `--share` command line argument for `git init` should enable this. The GitWiki has [a few words to say about this](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/g/i/t/GitFaq_ebc3.html#How_do_I_share_a_git_public_repository_and_use_it_in_a_CVS_way.3F). This should do the trick:

```
git --bare init --shared=all
```

If you have already created your repository, you might be able to convert it to a "shared repository" by throwing this command:

```
git repo-config core.sharedRepository true
```

in your repository, as mentioned in [a blog post at moserei.de](http://web.archive.org/web/20100728073046/http://moserei.de/index.php/58/shared-git-repo-ssh-umask-problems).

2014 update:
This is still possible but the command has changed from repo-config to config.

```
git config core.sharedRepository true
```

Comment: Is there a way to retro-actively make a git repository --shared if you did an initial non-shared git init?

Comment: @Steve Folly: I belive the second code sample in my answer should solve this. Havn't really tried this myself, though.

Comment: @Jørn Schou-Rode: doh! sorry, I should have been paying more attention!

Answer (score 8):

Git is meant to be distributed. So, every user should be having a separate repository of his/her own. The above method contradicts this methodology. Apart from that, I suspect the permissions of the `.git` directory.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess the ownership of the `.git` directory are the problem.

You shouldn't use one source tree from different users - it's likely to lead to problems.

The `git` executable is not the issue. It should be owned by root, and have 755 permissions. (`-rwxr-xr-x`)

In other words you can use git from multiple accounts, but you shouldn't share a single working directory.

Answer (score 3):

Having the permissions of any executable set so that a normal user can overwrite the executable is a considerable security risk. (Try overwriting `/usr/bin/git` with a shell script that calls `rm -rf $HOME`.)

Change the permissions back to 755 and make git owned by root:root again. (Ubuntu's package manager would reset the permissions on the next upgrade anyhow unless you used `dpkg-statoverride(8)`)

I agree with those who say that it may not be a good idea to have multiple users share one git repository. If you still think that it is necessary, consider setting up a new group, `chgrp` the directory holding the repository and all the files therein to that group andset the  setgid bit on the directories. (The `--shared` parameter to `git init` may do some of this for you, too.) Then, add all the users to the group that should have commit rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify members using

```
members groupname
```

Then you can set the permission level for the username:groupname pair,

```
change the ownership
sudo chown -v -R username:groupname sprout
chmod -R g+w .git/*
```