# Remotely Installing Websites Using Git with Nginx

Tags: git, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've followed the example listed at this [site](http://cuppster.com/2011/01/30/using-git-to-remotely-install-website-updates/) in remotely adding my files to my server, however, I'd like to have all files owned by the `nginx:nginx` user:group so that I can access the files from my browser after pushing the files.

How do I go about amending the `post-receive` hook so that `nginx:nginx` becomes the owner of the files/folders pushed to the remote 'ubuntu` server?

I've tried the following `post-receive` hook, however, if the file is being amended I receive the error: `remote: error: unable to unlink old 'index.html' (Permission denied)`, shell script here:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.foo.com/htdocs
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
exec sudo chown -R nginx:nginx $GIT_WORK_TREE
```

Thanks advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually the result of a process not releasing those files (preventing the git checkout to do its jobs), as described in "[Git Checkout warning: unable to unlink files, permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199496/git-checkout-warning-unable-to-unlink-files-permission-denied)".

But it could also be the result of your `sudo` command to have worked successfully once, making any future execution of your hook fail because it no longer has the right to checkout as the '`git`' user.

If it is the case, your hook should `sudo` as `nginx:nginx` your current git command, instead of `chown` the end result (the web working tree).

---

The OP confirms:

> In the git `post-receive` hook I now have `exec sudo -u nginx -g nginx ~/test.sh` (`test.sh` contains the `GIT_WORK_TREE` contents above).
>   However, I'm getting another permission error: `remote: fatal: Unable to create '/home/ubuntu/foo.git/index.lock': Permission denied`.
>   After running `~/test.sh`, do I need to go back to `ubuntu:ubuntu`?

I suggests:

> Declare you repo as "`shared by all`" as in "[Using Git without Sudo in many accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367258/using-git-without-sudo-in-many-accounts)".

Which seems to solve the issue:

> I set the config to `shared=true` as per the post mentioned and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks VonC for your reply. I have changed the `htdocs` folder back to `ubuntu:ubuntu` and when I make a change to the `index.html` file on my local machine I `git add .` then `git commit -m "blah"` followed by `git push web`, the change is made to the remote server at `/var/www/www.foo.com/htdocs/` but the owner is still `ubuntu:ubuntu`. How would I change the ownership of the files on the server to `nginx:nginx`? Is it something a git hook can do? Thanks again.

Comment: @rs77 my point was for you to execute the script as `nginx:nginx` with `sudo`, in order for the `git checkout` to be executed as `nginx:nginx`. So your hook would contain only one line, the `sudo` command which would call *another* script (which checkout files), but call it with the right end user.

Comment: Thanks again VonC, in the git `post-receive` hook I now have `exec sudo -u nginx -g nginx ~/test.sh` (test.sh contains the `GIT_WORK_TREE` contents above), however, I'm getting another permission error: `remote: fatal: Unable to create '/home/ubuntu/foo.git/index.lock': Permission denied`. After running `~/test.sh` do I need to go back to `ubuntu:ubuntu`? Thanks again so much for your help.

Comment: You might had another `sudo` before you `sudo` (still in your hook) in order to protect `/home/ubuntu.foo.git` (and just that directory) as `nginx:nginx` before making the checkout. Then add a third `sudo` *after* your original `sudo` in order to protect that `.git` repo directory back to `ubuntu:ubuntu`.

Comment: That or declare you repo as "shared by all": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367258/using-git-without-sudo-in-many-accounts

Comment: Thanks VonC! I set the `config` to `shared=true` as per the post mentioned and it seems to be working now. Thank you!