# Git stash permission denied on production server

Tags: git, git-stash

I tried to do git stash on my production server using 'deploy' user, but it gives error as

```
/usr/lib/git-core/git-stash: 440: cannot create /app/app_name/.git/logs/refs/stash: Permission denied
```

The error doesn't show up for 'root' user.

what could be the reason for error and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Who is having the ownership for .git folder?

Comment: If you need to git-stash in a production environment, you have a serious problem.

Comment: You're correct but that doesn't solve my current problem. 1 hour ago git stash working and now it stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you have created your repo.
Try it with a repo created with [`git init --shared`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init), in order for multiple users of a same group to be able to access and write in your repo.

```
--shared[=(false|true|umask|group|all|world|everybody|0xxx)]
```

> Specify that the Git repository is to be shared amongst several users.
>   This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository. When specified, the config variable "`core.sharedRepository`" is set so that files and directories under `$GIT_DIR` are created with the requested permissions.
>   When not specified, Git will use permissions reported by umask(2).

You would find more in "[Using Git without Sudo in many accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367437/6309)".

For your current repo, make sure that `deploy` has the right to access `/app/app_name/.git`.

The [OP rtcoms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386803/rtcoms) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557906/git-stash-permission-denied-on-production-server/16557996?noredirect=1#comment23788506_16557996):

> 3 files were owned by `root` user. And it did work.

Comment: deploy user  has read/write access

ls -l .git
total 400


-rw-r--r--   1 root   root       41 Nov  5  2012 RENAMED-REF
drwxr-xr-x   2 deploy deploy   4096 Apr 29  2012 branches

similar for other files/folders in .git folder.

Comment: @rtcoms I don't see how a user can have write access to a `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root`. You will have to change to rights or the owner/group of that git repo directory.

Comment: yeah , I missed that . 3 files were owned by root user. And it did work. Thanks