# Permission Denied when pulling into git Repository

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions

I seem to have permissions issue with a git repository.

I git this error when I pull in a directory my Linux user did not create.

```
fatal: Unable to create '/home/---/.git/ORIG_HEAD.lock': Permission denied
```

My user is a member of a group called grp.  I changed every file to `grp:grp` and I still cannot pull.

Is there any thought on why this happens?  For what it's worth I changed the actual `/git/REPOSITORY` files also to `grp:grp`.

Of course, when I use `sudo` I can pull fine but I prefer not to do it this way.

Comment: What's your default umask?

Comment: If you used sudo once, you may have some files owned by root in there that're preventing you from writing. Run 'chown -R user:grp path/to/dir', where the path contains .git (i.e. path/to/dir/.git)

Comment: @synthesizerpatel  Hey that actually fixed the issue; but what about other users who pull to the same depository?  I just changed it to mine?

Comment: My apologies, I missed that part. You'll have to set the sticky bit on it probably. 'chgrp user:group <path>;chmod 4775 <path>', then anyone in group will be able to read/write to it. not very secure, and possibly could be done better.. but that should do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Git without Sudo in many accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367258/using-git-without-sudo-in-many-accounts)

Answer (score 3):

User: **root**

1) `rm -f ./git/ORIG_HEAD.lock`

2) `chown -R MY_USER_NAME ./git*`

3) `chgrp -R MY_USER_NAME ./git*`

4) `git pull`